# How to continue the decompressing step over system reboots ? zlib

Tags: gzip, zlib, large-files, deflate, lossless-compression

Say I have a 100GB compressed file, after 76% of uncompression, my device got rebooted by other events, then I simply want to recontinue the uncompression from that 76% mark where I last left off. That's it.

To help with this, I could control how files are compressed and archived.

But while uncompressing on device, no command line, only zlib APIs are available, or any new APIs that may require.

This is a repost, a reworded question, for clarity, I apologize for that. Previously Z_FULL_FLUSH was suggested, but I didn't understand how I will use that 76% mark's offset to initialize the zlib.

Much appreciate any feedbacks.
Thanks

Read thru the zlib's FAQ and annotated usage page for better understanding of how deflate, inflate are working together in compressed stream.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you don't even need to specially prepare the gzip file. You can save the state of inflation periodically. If interrupted, roll back to the previous saved state and start from there.

You can use `Z_BLOCK` to get `inflate()` to return at deflate block boundaries. This will be noted in `data_type` as documented in zlib.h. You would pick an amount of uncompressed data after which to save a new state. E.g. 16 MB. Upon reaching that amount, at the next deflate block boundary would save the  location in the compressed data, which is both a byte offset and bit offset within that byte, the location in the uncompressed data you saved up to, and the last 32K of uncompressed data, which you can get using `inflateGetDictionary()`.

To restart from the last state, do a raw inflate, use `inflatePrime()` to feed the bits from the byte at the compressed data offset, and use `inflateSetDictionary()` to provide the 32K of history. Seek to the saved offset in your output file to start writing from there. Then continue inflating.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the detailed solution.
It appears deflate block boundaries are not detected.

Comment: It appears deflate block boundaries are not detected.
After inflate(,Z_BLOCK), checking data_type for 0x40 (indicating state->last is TRUE), 
it seems at the very end of the uncompression, I see my logs indicating "state->last is TRUE".
This is after uncompressing nearly 300MB file successfully.  
Input files: from WinZip tool, that compresses and archives the files. Which are then process by unzReadCurrentFile(), which calls zlib's inflate(, Z_BLOCK). I am not sure how big the 'deflate blocks' are, and where is it set?

Comment: deflate block boundaries are most certainly detected. You might consider the remote possibility that you are doing something wrong, as opposed to the library being in error. You should post a new question with the code for what you're doing, what you're expecting, and what you're seeing instead. I can't tell what you're doing from the comment, and comments are not the place to ask new questions.

Comment: Most certainly, I am missing something in my code. Thanks, I will post a new question.